# Google Photo Shared libraries, then edit photos. But new versions will not be synced

Tags: google-photos

As I described in the title.
Google Photos only shared the original photos via shared libraries. Any edits by the original own will not be synced to the other party.

It is a little bit annoyed since most of people edit their photos later on, but Google shared the original ones and will not sync all changes later on.

Any suggestions to avoid this? I want to share the latest version of photos.

Thanks.

Comment: Edit the photos offline then reupload them maybe?

Comment: It could work but in a smooth wau. I thinks it's a design defect.